# How to get a child item into a variable on its own

Tags: powershell

I am relatively sure this is quite easy to do but my google fu is not running strong

At the moment I am doing:

```
add-pssnapin windows.serverbackup
get-wbsummary
```

This returns me:

```
NextBackupTime                  : 07/09/2012 12:00:00
NumberOfVersions                : 210
LastSuccessfulBackupTime        : 06/09/2012 21:00:13
LastSuccessfulBackupTargetPath  : \\?\Volume{bf315689-e5ed-11e1-a376-d067e5f384ea}
LastSuccessfulBackupTargetLabel : SBSERVE 2012_08_21 12:20 DISK_01
LastBackupTime                  : 06/09/2012 21:00:13
LastBackupTarget                : SBSERVE 2012_08_21 12:20 DISK_01
DetailedMessage                 :
LastBackupResultHR              : 0
LastBackupResultDetailedHR      : 0
CurrentOperationStatus          : NoOperationInProgress
```

What I want to do is get just the result portion (not its title into a variable) so for example $lastbackuptime = 07/09/2012 12:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PS> $wbs = Get-WBSummary   
PS> $lastbackuptime = $wbs.NextBackupTime
```